# Unsubscribing to an observable because of memory leak

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a back-end service which returns some data when we hit one of its endpoint using `HTTP` service. Now in angular, what we do is using `Observables`. We `subscribe` to an end-point. Something like this

```
constructor(private http : Http){
}

ngOnInit(){
   this.http.get('/api/posts').subscribe(response => {
      // Store data into class variable
   })
}
```

When we have subscribed to it. In the `next` section of a subscription. We have got all the data whatever it is going to come through response. Now there's nothing to come apart from the data what we received but still many people says that there's a memory leak if we don't unsubscribe to it. We usually unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()` life cycle method. What I actually want to know is, when the call is already completed , we have got the data from the server through the response and there's nothing to come more from it. Then why we need to `unsubscribe` it. I want to understand that memory leak concept specially.

Comment: There is no need to unsubscribe http request. Because it won't be called again after `OnInit`. Unsubscribe is required when you are subscribing for a Observable that could be change from other places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR;** No you don't need to unsubscribe to http calls.

You should always think of unsubscribing from your observables unless the observable completes, which is the case for the http calls observables.

There are many ways of unsubscribing, if you need only one result you can add `obs.pipe(first())` which will automatically completes after receiving the first result. You can also use the `async` pipe in angular, that subscribes and unsubscribes automatically when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the subscribe it releases a subscription in javascript to provide us a handle on the http call event callback 
Allowing us to cancel the in progress http call.
Since in this case you have not preserved that in variable so it remains in javascript memory anonymously as a future event/handler suppose webservice takes time to execute it has not returned but that subscription stays with component and there was a bug in angular which doesnt auto unsubscribe for these calls then that subscription will still hang around in javascript bundle.
For more references

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16261